# Cannot parse php inside html

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've been beating myself up trying to get my php parse inside my html. I have used the following in my .htaccess to no avail.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html - a dialog box pops up asking me to open a php file
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html - Same
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html - Same
AddHandler php-script .html - just doesnt parse but looking into the source code you can see the php
AddHandler php5-script .html - Same
```

I would like to point out as well that a normal .php file runs fine on the server.

What gives?

Comment: Are you adding this in a htaccess file or apache httpd.conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out. It has something to do with my doctype. short_open_tag is enabled so php is trying to parse  because it thinks its php.

Solution:

Need to print that particular line with proper php syntax

```
<?php echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"; ?> ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your server configuration. Go into your httpd.conf or .htaccess and change this line (or something close to it):

```
addtype application/x-httpd-php .php
```

to parse .html files like this:

```
addtype application/x-httpd-php .php .html
```

and then restart the server